# PHP Echo Statements don't show in Browser Output in Eclipse w/ XDebug?

Tags: echo, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am testing XDebug on Xampp using win7-64 with Eclipse PDT.  I am debugging a simple script that echoes statements.  I can step over these statements, but the internal web browser window doesn't show these statements until after the entire script has finished running.  I tried entering phpinfo() at the top of the script and it displays in the browser just fine immediately after stepping over it.  Has anyone run across this issue and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Editing the following lines in *php.ini* solved the issue for me:

```
implicit_flush = On
output_buffering = 0
```

Comment: Had the same problem with PHPStorm 2017.2, UniserverZXIII and Xdebug. Solved it with this answer. Lost almost a week trying to do it. Thanks @srinivasa

Comment: It worked for me ex XAMPP but now that I'm using 'Laravel Herd' and it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Add the ob_get_contents() Eclipse expression, you will see the buffer!

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's buffering output?
tried flush() ?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php